# Возможно ли из delphi открыть запароленный Excel файл?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Уважаемые программисты, недавно столкнулся с проблемой: не могу вспомнить пароль от Excel файла. И тут я подумал, если уж учусь программировать, то почему бы не попробовать взломать, подобрать или заменить пароль. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? может что-нибудь подсказать?

Comment: Воспользуйся готовым решением.
А для учебы можно взять задачу по проще, например, научится открывать обычные файлы (без паролей).

Comment: Круто! Большое спасибо! Начнем:)

Comment: Хакер ты наш 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поучиться можно тут http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-84634/unread-1/hl/excel+delphi/index.html и здесь http://www.drkb.ru/ (не все решения из этого руководства идеальны)